Android audio echo cancellation not working for external audio source
I'm trying to have an AudioRecord and an AudioTrack echo canceled so that when audio is played, it won't feed back into the AudioRecord. I've tried enabling echo cancellation and forcing the audio routing to external audio systems as shown in the below code, but it isn't working. When I plug into an external USB mic/speaker, it still feeds back and doesn't get echo canceled. If I connect to a Bluetooth mic/speaker like my car, it still feeds back. The only time it doesn't feed back is when I use the internal mic/speaker on the Android device. How can I get audio echo cancellation working with an external mic/speaker?
val audioManager = getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
audioManager.mode = AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION
audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn = false
audioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn = true

val bluetoothScoConnected = audioManager.isBluetoothScoOn
val wiredHeadsetConnected = audioManager.isWiredHeadsetOn
val isUsbHeadset = true
val earpieceMode = false

val targetTypes = ArrayList<Int>()
//add types according to needs, may be few in order of importance
if (bluetoothScoConnected) {
    targetTypes.add(AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BLUETOOTH_SCO)
} else if (wiredHeadsetConnected) {
    if (isUsbHeadset) {
        targetTypes.add(AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_USB_HEADSET)
        targetTypes.add(AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_USB_DEVICE)
        targetTypes.add(AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_USB_ACCESSORY)
    } else {
        targetTypes.add(AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_WIRED_HEADSET)
        targetTypes.add(AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_WIRED_HEADPHONES)
    }
} else if (earpieceMode) {
    targetTypes.add(AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BUILTIN_EARPIECE)
} else { // play out loud
    targetTypes.add(AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BUILTIN_SPEAKER)
}

var result: Boolean? = null
val devices = audioManager.availableCommunicationDevices

Timber.i("Number of devices: ${devices.size}")
outer@ for (targetType in targetTypes) {
    for (device in devices) {
        Timber.i("device: ${device.type}")
        if (device.type == targetType) {
            result = audioManager.setCommunicationDevice(device)
            Timber.i("setCommunicationDevice type:$targetType result:$result")
            break@outer
        }
    }
}

if (result == null) {
    Timber.i("setCommunicationDevice targetType NOT FOUND!!")
}

I also tried doing this on my AudioRecord, but it doesn't work. And yes both AcousticEchoCanceller & NoiseSupression are available on my device.
if (AcousticEchoCanceler.isAvailable())
{
    val echoCanceler = AcousticEchoCanceler.create(audioRecord.audioSessionId);
    echoCanceler.enabled = true
}
if (NoiseSuppressor.isAvailable())
{
    val noiseSuppressor = NoiseSuppressor.create(audioRecord.audioSessionId)
    noiseSuppressor.enabled = true
}


Have you been able to solve this issue?
